# How to display each array element in a new line in the prompt?

Tags: javascript

Object:

```
const poll = {
    question: 'What is your favourite programming language?',
    options: ['0: JavaScript', '1: Python', '2: Rust', '3: C++'],
    answers: new Array(4).fill(0),
    registerNewAnswer() {
        const language = prompt(`${this.question}\n${this.options}`);
    },
};
```

I am trying to create this with the prompt:

[image]

But instead:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the array with newlines to achieve your desired output.

```js
const language = prompt(`${this.question}\n${this.options.join('\n')}`);
```